# About contentsTransform. How 3D Transform matrix work?

Tags: ios, swift, matrix, scenekit

I heard that I can use contentsTranform modify the texture. But how? the contentsTranform is a SCNMatrix, from the doc I can use SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation、SCNMatrix4MakeRotation and SCNMatrix4MakeScale functions to create a Matrix. But I don't know how to display the texture like the second picture. the photoFrame is a 1:2 and the texture is 1:1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### **Twice Edit:**

I change the scale and offset and WrapT property in the material editor. And the effect is good. But when I run it, I couldn't get the same effect. So I try to program by change the contentsTransform property. But the scale, offset they both affect the contentsTransform. **So if the offSet is (0, -4.03) and the Scale is (1, 1.714), what is the contentsTransform**?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make a plane the same aspect ratio as the image, then add that to the frame node?

Comment: I have tried this solution, but I have many of photoFrame with different aspect ratio, and I want to create a simple way to choose image and modify it, then show in the photoFrame.

Comment: there are different image, not just you see in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@HaoDong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6508755/haodong)'s question post.

> Now I know what's solution.
>
> ##### First
>
> **Don't load .dae file as the SCNScene.** You are supported to use .scn file. The error happened because I use .dae file to modify texture in Scene Editor. Then I couldn't get the same result when I run it. After I changed it to .scn file and modify the texture. I get the right effect on real Device. **You can simply convert .dae to .scn file by ->Editor->Convert to SceneKit scene file format.**
>
> ##### Second
>
> Both offset and Scale value affect the value of `contentsTransform` property. I have modify the texture in the material Editor View. if the offSet is (0, -4.03) and the Scale is (1, 1.714) the `contentsTransform` property is `SCNMatrix4(m11: 1.0, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m14: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 1.714, m23: 0.0, m24: 0.0, m31: 0.0, m32: 0.0, m33: 1.0, m34: 0.0, m41: 0.0, m42: -4.03, m43: 0.0, m44: 1.0)`. By searching the doc, I found that how to get this property.
>
> ```
> var matrixA =  SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -4.0, 0)
> var matrixB = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, 1.345, 1)
>
> var b = SCNMatrix4Mult(matrixB, matrixA)
> ```
>
> **Make sure it is MakeScale * MakeTranslation**